# How to Write a test Class For this?

Tags: apex, unit-test

when  i am trying write a test class am getting this error

System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

am getting error at line:attach1.setContentType

code:

```
        LIST<Document> docmnt=[select id ,Name ,body, contenttype from Document Where id IN ('01563000000Dvch','01563000000Dvcr','01563000000Dvcm')];
        System.debug('docmnt'+docmnt);
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attach.setContentType(docmnt[0].contentType);
        attach.setFileName(docmnt[0].name);
        attach.setInline(false);
        attach.Body = docmnt[0].Body;

        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach1 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attach1.setContentType(docmnt[1].contentType);
        attach1.setFileName(docmnt[1].name);
        attach1.setInline(false);
        attach1.Body = docmnt[1].Body;

        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach2 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attach2.setContentType(docmnt[2].contentType);
        attach2.setFileName(docmnt[2].name);
        attach2.setInline(false);
        attach2.Body = docmnt[2].Body;

        //New instance of a single email message
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        // Who you are sending the email to
        mail.setTargetObjectId(recipient);
        mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa,efa1,attach,attach1,attach2});
        // The email template ID used for the email
```

//test class

```
    Folder fold = [Select Id From Folder Limit 1 ];


      List<Document> docList = new List<Document>();
  Blob body = Blob.valueOf('TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQu');

  for (Integer i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Document doc = new Document(Body = body,ContentType ='application/pdf', Name = 'Hello world! ' + i , FolderId = fold.Id);

   docList.add(doc);
  }

  INSERT docList;
```

Comment: You're hard-coding Ids in your query which won't exist from one Org to another. You need to create test data using a `@testSetup` annotated method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're hard-coding Ids in your query:

```
LIST<Document> docmnt=[select id ,Name ,body, contenttype from Document Where id IN ('01563000000Dvch','01563000000Dvcr','01563000000Dvcm')];
```

You're getting the Array Out Of Bounds Exception because the `List<>` is likely returning nothing, yet you're trying to access items at point 0, 1 and 2 which aren't there.

What you'll need to do is create some dummy documents for your query to use in a `@testSetup` annotated method which might look like below:

```
@testSetup static void test_data() {
  Folder fold = [SELECT Id FROM Folder LIMIT 1];

  List<Document> docList = new List<Document>();
  Blob body = Blob.valueOf('TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQu');

  for (Integer i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Document doc = new Document(
      Body = body,
      ContentType = 'application/pdf',
      Name = 'Hello world! ' + i,
      FolderId = fold.Id
    );

   docList.add(doc);
  }

  INSERT docList;
}
```

The above will create and insert 3 documents with the names: `Hello world! 0`, `Hello world! 1`, `Hello world! 2`.

You can then change your query to just:

```
[SELECT Id, Name, Body, ContentType from Document]
```

**Edit**

As DML isn't allowed on `Folder`, you should just be able to query for any folder to store the documents which I've edited above by removing the DML and using

```
Folder fold = [SELECT Id FROM Folder LIMIT 1];
```

Unless it's important that it's a specific folder, this should be enough.

Comment: Hi Dan Jones Thank u for your help ...but am  getting what is that bolb value

Comment: @chandu The blob value is just dummy information. For the purposes of a Unit Test, that's all it really needs to be. A Blob value means Binary Large OBject. In other words, it's a collection of binary data stored as a single entity. This would be the "content" of the Document.

Comment: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [FolderId]: [FolderId]  am getting this error

Comment: @chandu You need to create a folder record in the same method, then associate the Document with the Folder. See my edits.

Comment: thank u for your patience...am getting error :DML not allowed on Folder

Comment: I have Created a dummy Folder with name MY TEST and wrtitng the code like this  List<Folder> lstFolder = [Select Id From Folder Where Name = 'My Test' ]; 
//  Document doc = new Document(Body = body,ContentType ='application/pdf', Name = 'Hello world! ' + i,FolderId = lstFolder.Id);
getting err:  Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Folder>
               
               if(lstFolder.size() > 0)
               {
                   Document document = new Document(FolderId = lstFolder.get(0).Id, Name='Test Name',Keywords = 'Test');
                 }

Comment: @chandu. Try editing your question with your new code. It's hard to read in that little box! :)

Comment: I have Edited The code.

Thanks

Comment: @chandu See my edits. If DML isn't allowed on Folder, you should be able to query for *any* folder.

Comment: Sorry ...Am Getting Error 
expecting a right parentheses, found ','

Comment: @chandu You're creating a collection, `List<Document>` that should only have instances of Document in it. Look carefully at my answer and how to construct this. :)

Comment: Sorry I am getting this error
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: FolderId (invalid folder): [FolderId]

Comment: You've declared `lstFolder` as a collection, this just needs to be `Folder lstFolder`, not `List<Folder> lstFolder`.

Comment: @Dan.Sorry for delay..I have edited my code

Comment: @chandu Great. Are you getting an error?

Comment: ya getting same error

Comment: Thank u
I have Changed Code like
FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId()

its Working